# In the arc length formula, where do $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ represent?

Tags: differential-geometry

The length of a regular arc $x=x(t)$ is given by $$\int^b _a \sqrt{ \bigg(\frac{dx_1}{dt}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{dx_2}{dt}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{dx_3}{dt}\bigg)^2} dt$$

What do $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ represent?

Comment: Sometimes we write the coordinates as $x$, $y$, and $z$. Sometimes we write them as $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$.

Comment: You have $x(t) = (x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))$. The rate of change of position with respect to time (that is, velocity) is ${d x(t) \over dt} = ( {d x_1(t) \over dt} , {d x_2(t) \over dt} , {d x_3(t) \over dt} )$. The speed is given by the length of the vector, which is $\sqrt{ \bigg(\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{dx_3(t)}{dt}\bigg)^2}$.

Comment: Four answers have been posted and so far I am the only person who has up-voted the question. $\qquad$

Comment: @copper.hat  I understand now, because velocity is a vector quantity so then we can use Pythagoras to find out the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the point on the curve corresponding to the parameter value $t$.

$(dx_1,dx_2,dx_3)$ may by intuitively thought of as an infinitely small change in $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ corresponding to an infinitely small change $dt$ in the value of $t$.

The corresponding infinitely small distance that the point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ moves along the curve is $\sqrt{(dx_1)^2+(dx_2)^2+(dx_3)^2}$, given by the Pythagorean theorem.  The whole arc length is the sum of these infinitely many infinitely small distances; thus it is
$$
\int_{t\,:=\,a}^{t\,:=\,b} \sqrt{(dx_1)^2+(dx_2)^2+(dx_3)^2}.
$$
This is of course the same as
$$
\int^b_a \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx_1}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx_2}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx_3}{dt}\right)^2} \, dt.
$$
This last form is used when you know $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as a function of $t$, thus reducing the problem to that of evaluating a definite integral with respect to a scalar variable $t$.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $x = \langle x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3\rangle$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with three components.

If $x$ is written as a function of $t$, we have

$$x(t) = \langle x_1(t),\,x_2(t),\,x_3(t)\rangle$$

Comment: So essentially we are looking at the length of the curve in each of  x , y , z direction and adding it up?

Comment: $$\frac{dx_1}{dt}$$ can be thought of as how *fast* the curve is moving in the $x$ direction at time $t$, or with $dx_2/dt$, how fast the curve is moving in the $y$ direction at time $t$, etc.

Comment: I never understood this, what does it mean to say "how fast the curve is moving"?

Comment: @al jabra:  No, it is not the length in each direction and adding up; that is not even true for a line segment (Pythagorean theorem?) In fact the integrand should remind you of the Pythagorean theorem. Regarding your other question: the curve itself is not moving, that was poor explanation. Rather, think of a small object (a fly) moving along the curve; the partial derivatives are the projections of the velocity vector of the small object tracing the curve, interpreting $t $ as "time".

Comment: You can think of $x(t)$ as the path of a particle. At time $t$, the particle is at the coordinate $$(x,y,z) = \left(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t)\right)$$

So then it becomes not how fast the curve is moving, but rather how fast the particle is moving (which is hopefully more intuitively clear?).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Using $x$ for both the path and a coordinate may be confusing for op$\dots$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You're right. It is just that $x_1$-coordinate, $x_2$-coordinate, and $x_3$-coordinate is awkward. Also OP brought up $x$, $y$, $z$, and I agree with OP that those three are more readable. Maybe the original function can be rewritten $$r(t) = \,<x(t),\,y(t),\,z(t)>$$

Comment: Please: It's $\langle x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3\rangle$, not $< x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3>$. $\qquad$

Comment: @mathguy   So how does the velocity vector relate to length?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks.

Comment: @zubinmukerjee so how does the speed of the particle on the curve relate to the length of the curve?

Comment: @Aljabra You know what the position of the particle is as a function of time. Velocity, in any number of dimensions, is the derivative of the position vector with respect to time. The derivative of a vector is taken "component-wise" - each component is a function, and you take the derivative of each function.

Answer (score 0):

They are the three components of a point, $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, on the curve.  You could also write the point as (x, y, z) and the arclength of the curve as $\int_a^b \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2} dt$.